# Core Data: How do I add additional entities to an existing many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, database, core-data, many-to-many

If I have '**Category**' and '**Asset**' entities and they have an inverse many-to-many relationship called 'assets' and 'categories' respectively, how would I add an additional entity instance of either Category or Asset into the existing relationship set?

Do I get the existing set and turn it into a mutableSet add the new entity and write it back to the db?

That doesn't seem like a great way, i guess i need the equivalent to addObject: in my Managed Object Entity class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: FYI The Assets can exist in more than one Category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the `NSManagedObject` subclass files
"Category.h/.m" and "Asset.h/.m" then you can simply add an asset to a category with

```
[category addAssetsObject:asset];
```

or add a category to an asset with

```
[asset addCategoriesObject:category];
```

Comment: Jeez, that was simple, not sure why it seemed so hard. Thanks @Martin R